# How to accurately get Windows OS version with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, version

Every link I look at always mentions GetVersionEx, but that doesn't seem very helpful.

My method looks like this,

```
static int windowsVersion() {
       OSVERSIONINFO osvi;

   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
   GetVersionEx(&osvi);
   return osvi.dwMajorVersion;
}
```

Which I am running **Windows 8** and instead it returns **6**.

If I'm trying to accurately get their version of Windows, that isn't very helpful.

Note: I've also checked all the other variables. the dwMinorVersion returns a 4, build number returns something like 8400.

Comment: What do you mean by `isn't very helpful`?

Comment: @JesseGood Well I'd like to know exactly which windows version I'm running. If I'm running Windows 8, I'd like to see a way to actually see Windows 8, instead of a 6.

Comment: You know that you can write just `OSVERSIONINFO osvi = {sizeof(osvi)};` ? That zeroes out the other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both the Major and Minor Version Numbers.

> Windows Vista   6.0.6000
>    Windows 7  6.1.7600
>     Windows 8 64 bit  version on my PC returns 6.2.9200

Answer (score 5):

[Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx): For Windows 8, `dwMajorVersion` is 6 and `dwMinorVersion` is 2

Answer (score 3):

A `6` for `dwMajorVersion` can mean anything from Windows Vista and up. That's how Microsoft versioning works. `2` for `dwMinorVersion` should be either Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012. If `wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION`, you got Windows 8. All of this is explained on MSDN.